# Gyroscope scrolling using Input.gyro.eulerAngles.x reverses direction at 90°

Tags: unity, mobile, gyroscope

I am working on a project where I want to create a 'scrolling' effect using the gyroscope on mobile devices. The basic idea is that I have an `Image` object in my scene and I want to be able to show different parts of it based on device rotation with the gyroscope. For example, you see the wall of a room, and by rotating your phone you can turn to see different parts of the room (but in 2D).

For now I managed to move my `Image` using `Input.gyro.attitude.eulerAngles.x;` from `Gyroscope` like this:

```
protected void Update()
{
    var x = transform.localPosition.x;
    var gyroX = Input.gyro.attitude.eulerAngles.x;
    x += -gyroX * Speed;

    BackgroundImage.transform.localPosition =
        new Vector3(x, transform.localPosition.y, transform.localPosition.z);

}
```

The problem I am seeing is that when `Input.gyro.attitude.eulerAngles.x` reaches `86.0` it starts decreasing. Even if you are rotating your phone to the right, it changes its direction.

I checked the documentation, examples over internet, but didn't find anything about that.

The only rotation axis which I am interested in is X, because the app will be in portrait mode and I want to be able to move the image only horizontally (by x).

So the phone's rotation has to be similar to what a user would do while taking a panoramic photo:

[image: Example of device orientation]

If you have any idea what can cause that issue and how can I fix it, or any other suggestions for how can I achieve the thing I want to create, please share your knowledge.

Comment: You probably don't want to use Euler angles for this. They're good for specifying one complete orientation to be used as-is. They're not good for decomposing that orientation into component parts (each component can change meaning depending on the values of the other components) or for dynamically modifying/comparing orientations. Can you phrase your desired control scheme in terms of direction vectors, perchance? These behave in a more uniform & intuitive manner.

Comment: @DMGregory the idea which I am trying to achieve is that:
1. The main background image is centered and when I rotate my phone to left, the image should move according to the angle of rotation so the user can see the left part of the image.
2. If I rotate the phone to right, the idea is the same as above. Most of the stuff which I see over internet are for rotating the object, but since I am working on 2D, rotating the image is not an option, it has to move by X.

Comment: Try including a diagram in your question. Rotational movement plus different phone-holding orientations makes it easy for ambiguity to creep in.

Comment: Just edited the question, with a little bit more info about the thing which I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

`rotationRateUnbiased` will give you the change in rotation. Try summing the `rotationRateUnbiased.x` value by multiplying it by `delta.time` and speed. I had the same problem and solved like this:

```
float angle;
float speed = 100;

void Start()
{     
    Input.gyro.enabled = true;
    angle = 0;     
}


void Update()
{
    if (Input.gyro.enabled)
    {
        float gyroXin = Input.gyro.rotationRateUnbiased.y * Time.deltaTime * speed;
        angle -= gyroXin;

        // And do whatever you like with angle
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To pan your image based on the relative rotation of your phone, you'll want to use `Gyroscope.rotationRateUnbiased` instead of `Gyroscope.attitude`. The latter describes the current orientation of the phone, which means it will wrap around when you rotate your phone a full 360 degrees, and your magnitude depends on how far you are from Unity's global zero, not how fast you're turning your phone.

In contrast, `rotationRateUnbiased` gives the instantaneous speed of rotation about each axis, which sounds more like what you're looking for. Remember to scale the speed by `deltaTime` so your movement doesn't jump/stutter or show inconsistencies under framerate changes.

```
protected void Update()
{
    var x = transform.localPosition.x;

    // I'm assuming the x axis of the phone is the one crossing the phone's
    // long axis - the Unity docs are a bit coy about important details like this....
    var gyro = Input.gyro.rotationRateUnbiased.x * Time.deltaTime;

    x -= gyro * Speed;
    // You may want to clamp or wrap x here in your image space.

    BackgroundImage.transform.localPosition =
        new Vector3(x, transform.localPosition.y, transform.localPosition.z);
}
```

Comment: tried that, but the image is moving with a few pixels. checked the value which returns `Input.gyro.rotationRateUnbiased.x`, it's something like 0,0032242 / 0.0012323 ... I've used attitude, because it's the only object which gives me rotation angles as 0 / 360, but there is an issue as I described with decresing the value after reaching 86 degree.

Comment: So after
`var gyro = Input.gyro.rotationRateUnbiased.x * Time.deltaTime;  x -= (gyro * Mathf.Rad2Deg) * Speed; ` (btw Speed = 5f) , still has almost the same result, with a little bit more movement.

Comment: Then make `Speed` much much much bigger.

Comment: still lot more glitchy and not so accurate in my opinion..using `Gyroscope.attitude` was giving better results, but with the issue.

Comment: Then describe the glitches. We can't fix a problem without knowing what it is.

Comment: While rotating the phone to left for example, the value which returns is not always directed to that way, so the phone's gyro returns value > & < 0 and the image is moving to left and right, like shaking.